# How to use google spreadsheet api?

Tags: google-api, httprequest, google-sheets-api

So I would like a link that gives me data without having to login similar to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pFpytftOYiw&ab_channel=API-University) it is a tutorial for the v3 API.

On the docs it says what I want is a http request
which is
`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}`
but it gives me this error

`{ "error": { "code": 403, "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.", "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED" } }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of Sheets API, at least, an API key is required to be used even when the Spreadsheet is publicly shared. This is the current specification. So when you can use the API key and the Spreadsheet is publicly shared, you can retrieve the values from Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

But, if you cannot use the API key, how about the following endpoint?

#### Endpoint 1:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/pub?gid={sheetId}&output=csv&range={range}
```

#### Endpoint 2:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{spreadsheetId}/gviz/tq?gid={sheetId}&tqx=out:csv&range={range}
```

- At the above endpoints, the API key is not required to be used.
- In this case, please encode the value of `range` with the URL encode.

### Added:

About your following situation.

> Endpoint 1 gives me an error and endpoint 2 works but it downloads a .txt for me which I have no idea how to use.

In above endpoints, the sheet of the Google Spreadsheet is retrieved as the CSV data.

About your following new question

> I would use an API key but I don't know how like I would guess I should put it in the link somewhere but I'm not sure how.

When you can use the API key,

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheetId}/values/{range}?key={yourAPIkey}
```

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)

Comment: So I get this when using it: Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again. Endpoint 1 gives me an error and endpoint 2 works but it downloads a .txt for me which I have no idea how to use. I would use an API key but I don't know how like I would guess I should put it in the link somewhere but I'm not sure how.

Comment: end point 2 doesn't work either it gives me a text file that said )]}'
{"version":"0.6","status":"error","errors":[{"reason":"internal_error","message":"INTERNAL_ERROR","detailed_message":"Cannot load spreadsheet."}]}

Comment: @kid Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your 2 questions, I added the answers in my answer. Could you please confirm it? And, about your replying of `end point 2 doesn't work either it gives me a text file that said )]}' {"version":"0.6","status":"error","errors":[{"reason":"internal_error","message":"INTERNAL_ERROR","detailed_message":"Cannot load spreadsheet."}]`, unfortunately, I cannot understand the method for retrieving this error message. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.